# LESS - styling classes differently dependent on the parent element

Tags: css, less

I have some LESS styles similar to the following. Is there a technique in LESS that better handles what I am trying to achieve without having to duplicate the class name under each parent element?

```
span {

    .zero {
        color: #fff;
    }
}

div {

    .zero {
        color: #389c40;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to achieve what you're doing. Also, if there were, I seriously doubt you would save time by typing it.

One thing I would consider is setting your color as a reusable variable.

Comment: thanks for the input

Comment: using js would do it, but if you're looking for a pure css/less solution, there isn't one.

Comment: It's not a problem to invent some high-level mixin [doing all that](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/ef9416573132f471c1a72f27fc90bde5) in one line (there're other - near infinite - ways). Though the question *why* actually you're trying to avoid such duplication still remains - intentional mangling of some code *just* to reduce number of typed characters is usually a bad idea (it could be some other fair reason you want no duplication in this case, but you need to explain it as it directly will affect any suggested solution - yet again - there're many).

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks! the accepted answer below provided by torazaburo is what I was looking for. No intention of creating complicated mixins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could always do

```
.zero {
  span & { color: #fff; }
  div & { color: #389c40; }
}
```

Comment: This. This is what I was looking for. Wasn't aware the `&` after the selector references the parent

Answer (score 2):

Try using css variables:

```css
:root{
    --zColor: #fff;
}
.zero{
    color: var(--zColor);
}
div{
    --zColor: #389c40;
}
```